# How to know count of JSON objects in the file?

Tags: c++, json, boost

I have JSON file

```
    {
  "media": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "order": 1,

    },
    {
      "id": 1385,
      "order": 3,

    },
    {
      "id": 1289,
      "order": 2,

    }
  ]
}
```

with 3 blocks (objects) with the same fileds name ("id", "order"). In the presented example we have 3 blocks. I want to get 3 as answer for my request. How can I do it? If it possible, with the boost library. Next time I'll get another JSON file witch will contains 4 or 5 same blocks

```
{
  "id": 1234,
  "order": 1,
},
```

and I want to know count of those blocks in the JSON file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest: **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/698oKfsWq)**

```
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>

static auto sample = R"({
            "media": [{
                "id": 1234,
                "order": 1,
            },
            {
                "id": 1385,
                "order": 3,

            },
            {
                "id": 1289,
                "order": 2,

            }]
        })";

int main() {
    auto v = boost::json::parse(sample, {}, {.allow_trailing_commas=true});

    return v.at("media").as_array().size();
}
```

Returns 3

Note that there are **much** more efficient ways to do it using e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__stream_parser.html or even just https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__basic_parser.html

Comment: Thanks again! In your example of code, wich parsed we used? Stream or basic? Or other? And show pls in documentation the place where should have me see this example, how to get size of blocks.

Comment: Other: it just parses the entire JSON into "DOM" (`json::value`) and then answers the question. The implementation of `parse` (probably) uses `stream_parser` which uses `basic_parser`. In other words, we used the most high-level interface.

Comment: I have some problems with compile of your example. auto v = boost::json::parse(output, {}, { .allow_trailing_commas = true }); No instance for overload this function. Argument list doesn't match with overload functions in this json::parser

Comment: Designated initializers are c++20. Making it c++11: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/ErhsG7Efa

Comment: But I want to give string as a sample variable. Is there method with string variable as JSON?

Comment: The sample is already a  variable? By the way now the live demo doesn't timeout http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb3a2ccb13c16bce and https://compiler-explorer.com/z/9YnYarhxe

Comment: your second realisation with C++ 11 works fine! And with string parameter as JSON. Thanks!