# need to parse json file and put all subfields into 2-level array

Tags: c++, json, boost

```
JSON:
{
    "media": {
        "Test1": "https://storage.tst",
        "Test2": "https://storage.tst"
    }
}
```

I need to put those keys (Test) and it's value in to 2-level array in cycles

Like @sehe offered, I used next code:

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
//#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
//(in the another file I already included <boost/json/src.hpp>)

std::map<std::string, std::string> not_an_array;

for (auto& kvp : sample.at("media").as_object()) {
    not_an_array.emplace(kvp.key(), kvp.value().as_string());
}
```

But I got an error "sample" is undefined. I suppose, I should include some json header for it. But, I have included it.
C++11.

Comment: I'm guessing you're asking about the answer given at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72500250/5494370, `sample` is the string containing your json data

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes and no. I'm fixing the answer up right now

Comment: @Alan Birtles, no, I asked about another task.

Comment: @sehe- sample- this is name of JSON. Understand it.

Comment: Yeah it was about this deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74434536/85371. Closed as a dupe, because all the info was literally already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the other lines of code that @sehe provided as well:

```
auto sample = boost::json::parse(R"(
{
    "media": {
        "Test1": "https://storage.tst",
        "Test2": "https://storage.tst"
    }

})");
```

They [conveniently included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434536/parse-json-file-on-c-and-take-all-subfilelds-of-main-key#comment131407704_74434739) a live demo:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8736e9e9aeb911e0)**

```
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace json = boost::json;

int main() {
    json::value sample = json::parse(R"(
        {
            "media": {
                "Test1": "https://storage.tst",
                "Test2": "https://storage.tst"
            }

        })");

    std::map<std::string, std::string> not_an_array;

    for (auto& kvp : sample.at("media").as_object()) {
        not_an_array.emplace(kvp.key(), kvp.value().as_string());
    }

    fmt::print("not_an_array: {}\n", not_an_array);
}
```

### But C++11?

They also included a C++11 example:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/E65TdMooT)**

```
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace json = boost::json;

int main() {
    json::value sample = json::parse(R"(
        {
            "media": {
                "Test1": "https://storage.tst",
                "Test2": "https://storage.tst"
            }
        })");

    std::map<json::string_view, json::string_view> not_an_array;

    for (json::object::value_type& kvp : sample.at("media").as_object()) {
        json::string_view k = kvp.key();
        json::value&      v = kvp.value();
        not_an_array.emplace(k, v.as_string());
    }

    for (auto& pair : not_an_array) {
        std::cout << pair.first << " -> " << pair.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I have json, received from file a stream like
std::string output = strStream.str(); And how to conver this "output" to the json::value samle?

Comment: The same way, friend. `boost::json::parse(output)`

Comment: thanks. Compiller found an error in the  C++11 example

Error (active) E0433 qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type "boost::json::object::value_type &" to initializer of type "const boost::json::object::value_type"

at the string
`for (boost::json::object::value_type& kvp : sample.at("media").as_object()) {`

Comment: Okay, funny, I included live examples for a reason (to show it compiles, even with MSVC: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/53K1rWYo1). You can also fix the error as your compiler sees it, just add `const`: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/zjaqvdocY (You're obviously using some different combination of  Boost version/compiler)